# GPS tracker to a custom web service

Tags: web-services, gps, tracker

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but does anybody know a GPS tracker device in which you can set your own url from your own web service? I've been looking and they all have their own software, app or web page. I need to develop a web service that does certain things with the data from the tracker, so I need the tracker to send the data to that web service. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For example, many Android smart phones have GPS. You can use such a smart phone and develop an app for it. In this app, you can access the GPS service and send data to your web service.